# Count function with postgis and counting 0

Tags: postgis

I have been using postgis for only a week and I'm already stucked. I'm working with the NYC gDB.
It's the one that is explained on this page : http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/about_data.html

I am trying to list the neighboroughts which are next to the neighborhood 'Woodhaven-Richmond Hill' and the number of subway stations located in those neighborhoods.

Now when I look at the map, I see there are 7. One of those is Glendale, it has no subway station, and when I write my query, it will not list it.. I want it to be listed and display '0' for the count.

```
select n2.name, n2.geom, count(u.geom)
into glendale
from nyc_neighborhoods n1, nyc_neighborhoods n2, nyc_subway_stations u
where n1.name='Woodhaven-Richmond Hill'
    and (st_touches(n1.geom, n2.geom) or st_overlaps(n1.geom, n2.geom)) and ST_Contains(n1.geom, u.geom)
group by n2.name, n2.geom
```

I know the problem is this : and ST_Contains(n1.geom, s.geom)
because it is fault for glendale...

Thanks !